# Passing props (array) to vue.js via blade (laravel)

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

How can i pass an array in vue js via laravel(blade)? 
I tried to do so :

//$users - array
blade:

```
<all-users users="{{ $users }}"></all-users>
```

vue:

```
<tr v-for="user in users" >

                    <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ user.login }}</td> 
</tr>
```

js:

```
export default {

    props:['users']
    }
```

//don't working all

P.S I tried also: 
 `<all-users users="{{ $users[0]->toJson() }}"></all-users>`
Output:

```
{"id":2,"email":"usersss@mail.ru","login":"SimpleUser","role_id":0,"images":"public\/img\/default_avatar.png","created_at":null,"updated_at":null}
```

In advance thanks for help

Comment: you say that your ouput return `object` but why do you loop your object in your vue?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
<all-users :users='@json($users)'></all-users>
```

or

```
 <all-users :users='{{ json_encode($users) }}'></all-users>
```

Comment: I receive all data in json format. 
How can i sort it in vue js? Via "v-for" - don't work

Comment: You can sort the json by `@json($users->sortBy('name'))`

Comment: the answer needs to updated with @hasan-wahajat, if using json use single quote, and add semicolon :

Comment: So, I have a case where one value in my json contains ' (single quote)  like `daniel's` and it still crashes the app. (I have tried escaping it at php level with every possible way but of no use)

Answer (score 8):

To pass data from laravel to vue your best option is using the @json option provided by Laravel. So your code will be like so:

```
<all-users :users='@json($users)'></all-users>
```

Keep in mind that you need to use single quotations @json function. Also don't forget to use ":" for your user prop otherwise it will be interpreted as string.

Laravel docs for json data:
https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#displaying-data

Answer (score 1):

```
<all-users :users='@json($usersInfo)'></all-users>
```

Also, keep in mind that you can't use a camel case here. It should be:

```
 <all-users :users='@json($usersinfo)'></all-users>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
in Blade:

<div id="app">
  <all-users users="{{ $users }}"></all-users>
</div>

get in Vue:
 
export default({
  props:['users'],

  mounted: {
    console.log(this.users); // return your users
  }

});
```